# Emacs: Symbol's value as variable is void

Tags: emacs

This is my `~/.emacs` file:

```
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4 c-default-style "linux")
(setq-default tab-width 4 indent-tabs-mode t)
(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
```

I'm getting a warning when I open up emacs:

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading
>   `c:/home/.emacs`:
>
> Symbol's value as variable is void: `c-mode-base-map`
>
> To ensure normal operations, you should investigate and remove the
>   cause of the error in your initialization file. Start Emacs with the
>   `--debug-init` option to view a complete error backtrace.

I ran `--debug-init` and this is what it returned. I don't know what I means:

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable `c-mode-base-map`)
>
> ```
> (define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "RET") (quote newline-and-indent)) 
>
> eval-buffer(#<buffer *load*> nil "c:/home/.emacs" nil t)
>
> ; Reading at buffer position 311
> load-with-code-conversion("c:/home/.emacs" "c:/home/.emacs" t t)
>
> load("~/.emacs" t t)
> ```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

What this means is that, at the point at which you invoke `define-key`, `c-mode-base-map` is not yet defined by anything.

The usual fix is to find out where this is defined and require that module.  In this case:

```
(require 'cc-mode)
```

However there are other possible fixes as well, for example setting the key-binding in a mode hook, or using `eval-after-load`.  Which one you use is up to you; I tend to do the KISS approach since I don't generally care about startup time; but if you do you may want something lazier.

Comment: Thanks. I'm also getting the same thing for `achead:include-directories`. Any ideas?

Comment: No clue about that one.  It sounds like something from an extension, not something distributed with Emacs.