# Emacs map <compile "python current-buffer-name"> to a hotkey

Tags: emacs, elisp

If I do `M-x <RET> compile <RET>`, I get prompted for what to compile. What I want to compile is the current buffer in python, so I type `python test.py <RET>`. Now sometimes I get asked if I want to create a separate process, and I always want to say `y` (that is yes).

`(define-key python-mode-map "\C-b" 'compile)` gives the following error:

[image]

`(define-key global-map "\C-b" 'compile)` works, but that's far from what I need.

So, how can I map `compile python current-buffer-name` to `"\C-b"` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512527/emacs-symbols-value-as-variable-is-void

Answer (score 0):

Emacs does have the concept of modes. I guess you do not want to have the compilation of python to a global key.

Have you checked:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs?action=browse;oldid=PythonMode;id=PythonProgrammingInEmacs

What you do is calling an external program. I'm sure there is a better suited way to do that in the python-mode.

If you want to pack more then one command to a key, you have to write some kind of wrapper this function contains all the things you are going to call.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `python-mode-map` will not be defined until you load `python-mode`.  The brute-force approach would be to `(require 'python-mode)` from your `.emacs` but you can avoid that somewhat more elegantly by only doing the define when `python-mode` is being invoked.

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key python-mode-map "\C-b" #'compile)))
```